# Why does this method for pluralizing category names not work in all cases?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS = "hardware",'memory'
def pluralize_category_name(name)
  category = name.split(' and ')
  exceptions_to_exp = ""

  category.map! { |e| 
    if e.match(/^[A-Z]+$/)  and !e.match(/^[A-Z]+S$/)
      e = e.pluralize
    end
    (PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS.include?(e.downcase)  || e.match(/^[A-Z]+S$/) ||
      e.match(/[memory|hardware]/) )? e : e.pluralize
  }.join(' and ')
end
```

The test should and expectation should be as follows:

```
it "properly pluralizes hardware as hardware" do
   pluralize_category_name("hardware").should == "hardware"
end

it "properly pluralizes UPS as UPS" do
   pluralize_category_name("UPS").should == "UPS"
end

it "properly pluralizes PDA and Portable Hardware as PDAs and Portable Hardware" do
   pluralize_category_name("PDA and Portable Hardware").should == "PDAs and Portable Hardware"
end

it "properly pluralizes perfume and cologne as perfumes and colognes" do
   pluralize_category_name("perfume and cologne").should == "perfumes and colognes"
end
```

The last test fails :(

HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that in your condition

```
(PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS.include?(e.downcase)  || e.match(/^[A-Z]+S$/) ||
      e.match(/[memory|hardware]/) )? e : e.pluralize
```

`"perfume"` matches `/[memory|hardware]/`.

`[memory|hardware]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any of `m`, `e`, `m`, `o`, `r`, etc..

Perhaps you meant `e.match(/(memory|hardware)]/i)` instead? This alternative pattern would pass your tests but it doesn't make use of your `PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS` constant so would need updating if you added any other exceptions.

Comment: also, you could do `/(#{PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS.join '|'})/` to have the regexp catch any of your defined exceptions.